# Почему я могу использовать fetchAll() в классе PDOStatement только 1 раз?

Tags: php, pdo

Доброго времени суток. Не очень понимаю, почему я могу использовать `fetchAll()` только 1 раз? Во второй раз возвращается пустой массив

```
$statement = $pdo->query($someSql);

$a = $statement->fetchAll();
$b = $statement->fetchAll(); // empty array
```

Почему так происходит? Ведь, как я правильно понимаю, результат запроса (результирующий набор) хранится в `$statement` после выполнения `query()`? Что мешает получить его еще раз?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> PDOStatement::fetchAll() возвращает массив, содержащий все **оставшиеся** строки результирующего набора.

Обратите внимание на слово "оставшиеся" и подумайте:
Вы выполнили первый `fetchAll`, он вернул все записи набора. Что ещё осталось?
Да ничего, пусто.
Вот именно его и вернёт второй `fetchAll`.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что PDO `fetchAll` отбирает оставшиеся записи. Следовательно после первого прохода таких записей не остается. Для того, что бы заново отобрать данные с помощью этого метода надо вернуть текущую позицию курсора в начало записи. По умолчанию курсор открывается в режиме "только вперед" `PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY`.

Вы можете изменить это поведение установив курсор в режим `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL`.

```
$db->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
```

Однако стоит иметь ввиду, что MySQL до недавнего времени не поддерживало курсоры и попытка провернуть подобное на ней закончится провалом. Поэтому безопасней сохранять записи в промежуточном хранилище или повторять запрос после закрытия курсора `$statement->closeCursor()`.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что такой код не имеет ни малейшего смысла.

Получив массив один раз, его можно использовать сколько угодно, **без** обращения к слою для работы с БД.